# Request to burn [microsoft]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

This is a popular request among web developers, however, I'm talking about the tag [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) which has almost 3k questions.

Its description is:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG!!! This tag is too general to be useful. Use tags more relevant to the software or device you're targeting.

Which I have to agree with.

Can we have a cathartic burning?

Comment: As a web dev, I'd prefer a ritual burning... Either way, `Request.agree()`

Comment: MSE related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190914/are-company-name-tags-like-microsoft-and-apple-useful/190916#190916 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199189/blacklist-the-microsoft-and-apple-tags

Comment: I tried last year to untag [microsoft] questions, and the tag is like a damn hydra; you untag one question, and two more take it's place.  After two weeks, I got bored.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: Hende the suggestion to blacklist it on MSE

Comment: @Cerbrus - yeah, but there doesn't seem to be much interest, since the last question got closed as off-topic of all things, and here we are, over a year later

Comment: @bluefeet: duped now that Tim migrated it. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yup, I was waiting for the migration after asking him.